# Determine E(X) in terms of E(Y) and V(X) in terms of V(Y)

Tags: variance, means, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ have respective cumulative distribution functions $F_x$ and
$F_y$, and suppose that for some constants $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b > 0$,

$F_x(x) = F_y((x − a)/b)$

(a) Determine $E(X)$ in terms of $E(Y)$ and $V(X)$ in terms of $V(Y)4.

I'm not sure about $V(X)$ but I think $E(X)$ should be $(E(y)-a)/b.$ Would this be right?

Comment: Hint: $X$ has same distribution as $a+bY$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of notation, let's say $Y$'s CDF and density are $G(y)$ and $g(y)$ respectively. We have $f(x) = \frac{1}{b}g(\frac{x-a}{b})$, from which we have $EX = \int xf(x)dx = \int (bz+a)g(z)dz = bEY+a$.

From linearity of $E$ you can guess $Var(X) = b^2Var(Y)$. Also, it is not too difficult to go through the change of variables in the integration to evaluate $EX^2 = \int x^2f(x)dx$ as in $EX$.